# Sending message from ActiveMQ to topic subscribers in docker container

Tags: windows, networking, docker, mqtt

I have an application in a docker container which is a `mqtt-client`.

I have installed in host (windows) ActiveMQ-Broker which has an interface of mqtt: `0.0.0.1:1549`

(Actually, I can call winwows-PC as super-host. Docker containers are run in WSL2-host (Debian) which is on Windows-Host.

Docker containers are configured with default network settings, e.g. `bridged network`, without exposing any port.

My `mqtt client` on docker-container can successfully connect to ActiveMQ broker that runs on host-windows, through `Host-IP:1549`

My `mqtt client` on docker-container subscribes to a topic.

Then, I send a message to that topic using ActiveMq admin console:

[image]

Unfortunately, my `mqtt client` on docker-container does not receive that message.

I have run another mqtt client on windows and subscribed to the same topic, to confirm that `ActiveMq Broker` successfully sends the message to subscribers, and seen that, yes, mqtt client on windows receives the message without problem.

**Can the problem happen because `docker-container` can reach to `windows-host`, but `windows-host` cannot write to all ports of `docker-container`?**

I see the connection established in ActiveMQ like this:

[image]

Does this mean I should have exposed the port `3718` when doing `docker run`, in order AciveMq in windows host to send message to docker-container? But supposing, this port changes every time, what would I do?

How can achieve that ActiveMQ broker on Windows-Host send message to subscribers running on `docker-container`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not networking. So, the answer to the quesion is:

**If docker-container-client connects to the broker, then broker can send to docker-container-client the message without problem.**

The problem was silly: Actually, in low-level, the message was being received, but it was failed to see it in high-level of code.